# Downgrade Aura Component API version

Tags: lightning-aura-components, visualstudiocode, api-version

I am trying to downgrade aura component api version to 39.0 from visual studio code, and push it back to sandbox. I can see that it's been changed in visual studio, but hasn't changed in Salesforce environment when I am checking it from UI.[image: Aura Component Metadata] I am also trying to delete some lines of code from client side controller, having same issue there as well, I can see deleted lines in developer console but not in visual studio.

Comment: I'm not sure if its because of the api that you're selecting, but if you go into the UI and open the component in the dev console, you can click on component bundle version and change the api version from there, but Salesforce limits you to only a few versions ago, and 39 is not available for me. This may be why it is not pushing to Salesforce from the IDE (maybe it's being blocked because the version that you have selected is too old for SFDC to allow).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the below SOQL in Developer Console and update "ApiVersion" directly from there.

```
SELECT Id, DeveloperName, ApiVersion, Description FROM AuraDefinitionBundle WHERE DeveloperName = "<Component name>"
```